# HTML video player time to hide controlls

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, html5-video

I'm trying to add short video (less than 3 seconds) to html page via `<video>` tag. Is there any possibility to decrease controls hide time?

Comment: What Did you try so far? provide your current code

Comment: I actually don't have any. I have no idea how to even start.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to hide the controls completely?

If you omit the "controls" attribute from the video tag it will not render them on the video, try removing it here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_controls

If you would like to still have the controls, then I would add some custom buttons/links and use JS to toggle play/pause. Not sure if that's what you need though, could you be more specific? :-)

Comment: w3schools?? :'(

Comment: I want to have short videos (as i said before less than 3 sesonds) that can be played looped in fullscrean. But when video is shorter than about 3 seconds controls won't hide and will be visable.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I hope this code helps you. Be sure to change the width and height in the `<video>` tag to suit your needs and keep in mind you have to correctly call to the paths of your videos in the `src=` and keep them in those quotation marks so it works correctly!

By not including "controls" in the `<video>` tag then those controls should not appear. the `autoplay="autoplay` automatically plays your videos.

**HTML**

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="yourpathherepath/videofilename.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="yourpathherepath/videofilename.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Sorry! Your browser isn't compatible with the Videos on our website!
</video>
```

**CSS**

Here I put a little CSS on it so a user can't even click the videos to possibly control them. You can experiment with this and see if you want to use it!

```
video{
  pointer-events: none; /* Disable any user interaction at all */
}
```

Best of luck and in the future it's best to use websites like [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) to try out your code and then people here can see a live demo and help you find a solution!